# Show newest questions in profile page, not top questions

Tags: support

When I visit my stackoverflow.com profile, it shows my newest
questions by default:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/354134/barrycarter

When I visit my stackexchange.com profile, however, it shows my top questions:

https://stackexchange.com/users/144803/barrycarter

with no apparent option to show my newest questions instead.

How to fix?

Comment: This is probably gonna be tagged as "by-design". I think they want your global profile to show your best stuff from across the network only.

Comment: Actually, the site profile pages will show your top questions by default. But the tab is sticky. At some point in the past, you clicked the "newest" tab and it has stuck since.

Comment: @Mysticial You are correct! It defaults to sort by votes. Never noticed that before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some poking around, you can get to something close by clicking on the `activity` tab, and the `posts` subtab

https://stackexchange.com/users/144803/barrycarter?tab=activity

It seems to be listing both your questions AND answers, but it looks like it's in chronological order, and you should be able to find your new stuff from there.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! http://stackexchange.com/users/activity/144803?page=1&filter=posts gets even closer by filtering out awards and other stuff.